# javascript private inner functions in module with access to "this" scope

Tags: javascript, function, scope

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Javascript outer scope variable access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2274162/javascript-outer-scope-variable-access)

I have a javascript module that looks something like below. The main issue I'm having is how to access variables in the "this" scope from the private `someOtherFunc`. Is there a way to access `this.myvar` in the private `someOtherFunc`

```
var mymodule = (function(){

    return {   
        MyObj : function() {

            this.myvar = 123;

            this.publicfunc = function() {
                someOtherFunc();
            };

            var someOtherFunc = function() {
                //this doesn't seem to work
                this.myvar = 456;
            };

        }
     }
}
```

The idea is that I want to be able to do something like

`new mymodule.MyObj().publicfunc`, but make the `someOtherFunc` private

Comment: `someOtherFunc.call(this)` instead of `someOtherFunc()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forget my previous answer. You *can* do this just by adding a private version of *this*.

```
var mymodule = (function() {
    return {   
        MyObj : function() {
            this.myvar = 123;
            var that = this;

            this.publicfunc = function() {
                someOtherFunc();
            };

            var someOtherFunc = function() {
                that.myvar = 456;
            };
            return this;
        }
    };
});
```

Bear in mind that, with your code, every time you call MyObj you get *a new object*.
So this would do what you want:

```
>var o = new mymodule().MyObj()
>o.myvar
123
>o.publicfunc()
>o.myvar
456
```

but not this

```
>var m = new mymodule()
>m.MyObj().myvar
123
>m.MyObj().publicfunc()
>m.MyObj().myvar
123
```

If that's not what you want, consider doing something like this

```
var mymodule = (function() {
    var myObj = null;
    this.MyObj = function() {
        if(myObj != null)
            return myObj;
        myObj = {};
        myObj.myvar = 123;

        myObj.publicfunc = function() {
            someOtherFunc();
        };

        var someOtherFunc = function() {
            myObj.myvar = 456;
        };
        return myObj;
    };
});
```

Comment: But now someOtherFunc is a public function, right? I don't want instances of MyObj to be able to access someOtherFunc

Comment: @JeffStorey See changes in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Why not build it a little more deliberately?

```
// this one returns an object used like:
// myModule.myInt; /* 456 */
// myModule.myFunc(); /* 124 */
var myModule = (function () {
    var secretData = 123,
        publicData = 456,

        publicFunc = function () { return privateFunc(secretData); },
        privateFunc = function (num) { return num + 1; },

        public_interface = {
            myInt  : publicData,
            myFunc : publicFunc
        };

    return public_interface;

}());
```

I went through the trouble of explicitly naming the returned, public object, but it's now very clear what is and isn't public, and yet, each one of those things will have access to the variable versions of one another, with the one exception being that if you change `myModule.myInt` or `publicData`, they will no longer be equal.

---

To demonstrate what I mean in the comments below, creating multiple instances with their own private data/methods, I just add in one more layer of function-scope:

```
var myModule = (function () {

    var static_int = 789,

        makeInstance = function (/* any constructor values */) {
            var secretData = 123,
                publicData = 456,

                publicFunc = function () { return privateFunc(secretData); },
                privateFunc = function (num) {
                    console.log(static_int);
                    return num + 1;
                },

                public_interface = {
                    myInt  : publicData,
                    myFunc : publicFunc
                };

            return public_interface;
        };

    return makeInstance;
}());
```

You now use it like:

```
var newModule = myModule(/* instance parameters */);
newModule.myFunc();
```

...or

```
var num = myModule(/* instance parameters */).myFunc();
```

If you wanted to save memory, you could have static *helper functions* inside of the static-layer:

```
var myModule = (function () {

    var static_int = 789,

        static_addOne = function (num) { return num + 1; },
        static_divideBy = function (dividend, divisor) { return dividend/divisor; },

        makeInstance = function (/* any constructor values */) {
            var secretData = 123,
                publicData = 456,

                publicFunc = function () { return privateFunc(secretData); },
                privateFunc = function (num) {
                    console.log(static_int);
                    return num + 1;
                },

                public_interface = {
                    myInt  : publicData,
                    myFunc : publicFunc
                };

            return public_interface;
        };

    return makeInstance;
}());
```

And now you have "private" functions which are only written one time (ie: you save memory), but any instance can use those functions.

**Here's the catch:**
Because of how scope and closure work, the static functions have ***NO*** access to values ***inside*** of the instance (functions inside have access to the static functions, not the other way around).

So, any static helper functions ***MUST*** have the values passed to them as arguments, and if you're modifying a number or a string, you ***MUST*** return the value out of that function.

```
// inside of a private method, in any instance
var privateString = "Bob",

    privateFunc = function () {
        var string = static_helper(privateString);
        privateString = string;
        //...
    };
```

Comment: But what if each instance of the public_interface needs its own secretData?

Comment: Then put all of the inner stuff inside of a function and return the function, unless you ALSO need "static" data, to share between instances, in which case, you would define the "static" vars in the outer function, and then reference them from within the function you return (which builds instances).

Comment: Can privateFunc access secretData in this case? (if each instance of myModule had secretData)? Can you show an example of how that's done?

Comment: I hope the edited version helps. Short-story: each instance would need its own copy of `privateFunc`. That increases memory (not an issue unless you're making hundreds of thousands of these), but allows for private methods with access to private data. You can also have ***static*** data and static methods which any instance can use or modify...  ...***BUT*** the static methods can't access private data, so you have to provide arguments, and collect return statements from them.

Answer (score 1):

Declare `myvar` using the `var` keyword, making it private, then access it without the `this.`:

```
function MyObj(){

        var myvar = 123;

        this.publicfunc = function() {
            someOtherFunc();
        };

        var someOtherFunc = function(){

            alert(myvar);

        };            
}


var o = new MyObj();
o.publicfunc();
```

If you need public access to `myvar` then create a public getter/setter.

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mp7sz/)
​

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is a way to encapsulate `myvar` for changes.  When some of the other answers run, `myvar` usually will stay as `123` because the initially returned object from `mymodule` holds on to that initial value.

Return a function that gets the value of `myvar` even after it's been modified, and I think that helps your problem.

Here's the code that works for me:

```
var mymodule = (function(){
    var myvar = 123,
        publicfunc = function() { myvar = 456 },
        getMyVar = function() { return myvar; };

    return {
        someOtherFunc : publicfunc,
        myPublicVar : getMyVar
     };
}());

mymodule.someOtherFunc();
alert(mymodule.myPublicVar());​  //gives you 456
```

JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/dhoerster/MRcYh/).

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You don't `return` anything from `MyObj`.

```
return this;
```

should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Use the bind method:

```
var someOtherFunc = function() {
     this.myvar = 456;
}.bind(this);
```